# not able to click button using watin

Tags: c#, watin, webautomation

```
<div class="flow-right">
    <button type="button" id="btnClear_page" class="uiButton" title="Clear" onmouseover="JSButtonUtils.doBtnOver(this)" onmousedown="JSButtonUtils.doBtnDown(this)" onmouseout="JSButtonUtils.doBtnOut(this)" onclick="if(JSButtonUtils.debounce(this, 1200)){ return false } else { return btnClear_page_click(this, true, true);}  ">
      <div class="uiButton-content">
        <div class="uiButton-label">Clear</div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="btnSearch_page" class="uiButton primary" title="Search" onmouseover="JSButtonUtils.doBtnOver(this)" onmousedown="JSButtonUtils.doBtnDown(this)" onmouseout="JSButtonUtils.doBtnOut(this)" onclick="if(JSButtonUtils.debounce(this, 1200)){ return false } else { return btnSearch_page_click(this, true, true);}  ">
      <div class="uiButton-content">
        <div class="uiButton-label">Search</div>
      </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

I have above html code, button wrapped inside Div, I have tried to find the button and click on it, no luck and also tried clicking over Div no luck. Using IE9 browser and C#.

```
using (var browser = new IE("https://Site.com"))
            {
     browser.Div(Find.ByText("Search")).Click();
      browser.Button(Find.ById("btnSearch_page")).Click();
}
```

Comment: What browser are you trying this in?

Comment: How are you getting your `IE` object? Attaching, like this? `IE browser = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl("http://www.google.com"));`

Comment: And if you step through the code it gets values for `browser` and then it hangs on the `browser.Div(Find.ByText("Search")).Click();`?

Comment: no it is not, rather it says, it can't find the element with the attribute Search.

Comment: I would recommend splitting the retrieval of the DOM element out into separate line, like this: `var searchDiv = browser.Div(Find.ByText("Search"));`. This allows you to see whether or not finding the DOM element worked or not and then if so you can operate on the element on the next line, like this: `searchDiv.Click();`

Comment: I don't see a DIV in your markup with an ID of `Search`, are you showing all of your markup?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33941/discussion-between-janardhan-and-karl-anderson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had flaky experiences with WatiN in the past and I have always used guard clauses in my WatiN code to fend off `NullReferenceException`s, like this:

```
using (var browser = new IE("https://Site.com"))
{
    var SearchDiv = browser.Div(Find.ByText("Search"));
    // Only try to click the DIV if we found it
    if(null != SearchDiv)
    {
        SearchDiv.Click();
    }

    var SearchButton = browser.Button(Find.ById("btnSearch_page"));
    // Only try to click the button if we found it
    if(null != SearchButton)
    {
        SearchButton.Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found it, basic points were not verified, The control is in Iframe, I need to select Iframe first then child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe elements are considered as a different form elements,doesn't fall under the main form.
using the below code we can click any child elements under the iframe.

```
WatiN.Core.Frame frame = browser.Frame(Find.ById("frameMain"));
                var buttons = frame.Button(Find.ById("btnSearch_page"));
                if (buttons.Exists)
                {
                    buttons.Click();
                    browser.WaitForComplete();
                }
```